# Where should I put config beans with a Spring Modulith project?

Tags: java, spring, spring-modulith

In a Spring Boot project using `Spring Modulith` to structure the application.

When I add a subdir "config" with a bean definition, the app refuses to start. The file looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

  @Bean
  public SecurityWebFilterChain registerAuthenticationFilter(
    ServerHttpSecurity httpSecurity) {
  ....
```

I get error when starting the app:

```
Error creating bean with name ...
   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setSecurityWebFilterChains' parameter 0: 
   Error creating bean with name 'registerAuthenticationFilter' defined in class path resource 
    Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.server.SecurityWebFilterChain]: Illegal arguments to factory method
    'registerAuthenticationFilter'; args: org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.reactive.ServerHttpSecurityConfiguration$ContextAwareServerHttpSecurity@284bdeed
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.resolveMethodArguments(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:875) ~
```

When I put the file with the config bean in the root directory, then it the apps starts just fine.

The project strucuture looks like this:

```
/root
  application.java 
  /config
     WebSecurityConfig.java  <- this one is the problem
  /moduleA
  /moduleB
```

But when I have more config beans, and a lot of them are cross-cutting, I would like to put them in a own config directory. This seem to contradict the normal modulith convention. How do I organize the config beans when using Spring Modulith?

It is `Java 20` and `Spring Boot 3.1.4`

Comment: Spring Boot's scanning highly depends on packages. Can you post your package structure, so that we can examine a bit better your case?

Comment: @Livanow I added the module structure. It is modulith-1.0.1, I need to check is the problem still exists in 1.0.2.

Comment: The stack trace unfortunately lacks the interesting bits. It should actually tell you what bean was actually missing at the very bottom. I doubt this has anything to do with Spring Modulith, at least if the error occurs at runtime, as it doesn't interact with the component scanning there at all. `config` is becoming a module. To automatically include that in test runs, you might have to declare it as a shared module (through `@Modulithic` on your main application class) or explicitly include it in the test run (via `extraIncludes`).